# Nokogiri parsing string into xml

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

How can I change `Nokogiri::XML('<moreThan>8</moreThan><lessThan>13</lessThan>').children`

to return `<moreThan>8</moreThan><lessThan>13</lessThan>`

(because it only returns `<moreThan>8</moreThan>`)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

[Nokogiri::XML](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) parses an XML *document*. A valid XML document can have [*only one* root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling) so Nokogiri tries to make your document valid by ignoring the second (invalid) element.

You need to first make your document valid by wrapping it in a root element, then retrieve the children of that root element.

```
Nokogiri::XML("<myroot>#{myxml}</myroot>").root.children
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to wrap your XML like so?

`<parent><moreThan>8</moreThan><lessThan>13</lessThan></parent>`

The result of:

`Nokogiri::XML('<parent><moreThan>8</moreThan><lessThan>13</lessThan></parent>').children`

will then be:

`<moreThan>8</moreThan><lessThan>13</lessThan>`

Comment: the result is : `<parent><moreThan>8</moreThan><lessThan>13</lessThan></parent>` ... Really confused